# dplyr: Counts/Percentages of factor grouped by school not getting grouped

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a long dataset with one row per individual grouped with schools. Each row has an ordered factor {1, 2, 3, 4}, "cats". I want to get the percentage of 1's, 2's, 3's and 4's within each school. The dataset looks like this:

```
  school_number           cats
1          10505             3
2          10505             3
3          10502             1
4          10502             1
5          10502             2
6          10502             1
7          10502             1
8          10502             2
10         10503             3
11         10505             2
```

I tried something like this:

```
df_pcts <- df %>%
   group_by(school_number) %>%
   mutate(total=sum(table(cats))) %>%
   summarize(cat_pct = table(cats)/total)
```

but the total variable produced by the mutate() step puts the grand total number of rows in every row. I can't even get to the final summarize step. I'm confused.

P.S. In some other posts I saw lines like this:

```
n = n()
```

when I do that I get a message saying,

```
Error in n() : This function should not be called directly
```

Where did this come from?

TIA

Comment: what output do you need? separate columns for 1,2,3 cats or separate rows for each school/cat combination?

Comment: You could also use `df %>% group_by(school_number, cats) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% mutate(pct=100*n/sum(n))`

Comment: Could you type just `mutate` into your session, and confirm whether the last line of the output is `<environment: namespace:dplyr>`? If the output is instead `<environment: namespace:plyr>`, then that's exactly the problem: somehow plyr got loaded after dplyr was loaded (and plyr's mutate doesn't pay attention to group_by). This is a common cause (though not the only one) of "group_by doesn't work" problems.

Comment: @DavidRobinson, yes, the non-grouping was caused by mixing plyr and dplyr mutates. But even when I resolved that, my code using table failed, giving this message: Error in summarise_impl(.data, named_dots(...), environment()) : 
  dims [product 4] do not match the length of object [18] But the solution below worked fine.

Comment: @akrun, thanks for this, but I still get errors when I try to use n(). Where does this come from?

Comment: @Stuart Are you using `n()` *within* the `summarize` function? That's where it's meant to be used. If you are still giving errors perhaps you can show a full reproducible example (probably in a new question since it's not related to this problem)

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps this helps a little, though I'm not 100% sure of what output you need.

This counts the number of rows of each combination of school_number/cats that exist in your df using `tally`.  Then calculates the percentage of 'cats' in each school_number by then only grouping by school_number.

```
df %>%
  group_by(school_number,cats) %>%
  tally  %>%
  group_by(school_number) %>%
  mutate(pct=(100*n)/sum(n))
```

It gives this:

```
  #    school_number cats n       pct
  #  1         10502    1 4  66.66667
  #  2         10502    2 2  33.33333
  #  3         10503    3 1 100.00000
  #  4         10505    2 1  33.33333
  #  5         10505    3 2  66.66667
```

EDIT:

to add in rows with 0% that are missing from your sample data, you could do the following. Bind together the output above with a df that contains 0% for all school_number/cats combinations.  Only keep the first instance of this bind (first instances always containing values >0% should they exist).  I then arranged it by school_number and cats for ease of reading:

```
y<-df %>%
  group_by(school_number,cats) %>%
  tally  %>%
  group_by(school_number) %>%
  mutate(pct=(100*n)/sum(n)) %>%
  select(-n) 

x<-data.frame(school_number=rep(unique(df$school_number),each=4), cats=1:4,pct=0)  

rbind(y,x) %>%
  group_by(school_number,cats)%>%
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
  arrange(school_number,cats)
```

which gives:

```
#   school_number cats       pct
#1          10502    1  66.66667
#2          10502    2  33.33333
#3          10502    3   0.00000
#4          10502    4   0.00000
#5          10503    1   0.00000
#6          10503    2   0.00000
#7          10503    3 100.00000
#8          10503    4   0.00000
#9          10505    1   0.00000
#10         10505    2  33.33333
#11         10505    3  66.66667
#12         10505    4   0.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

All combination of school number and cats then left join in order to calculate pct. If NA then 0

```
expand.grid(school_number =  unique(df$school_number), cats = levels(df$cats)) %>%
  left_join(df %>%
              group_by(school_number, cats) %>%
              tally %>%
              mutate(pct = (n / sum(n) * 100))) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  mutate(pct = ifelse(is.na(pct), 0, pct)) %>%
  arrange(school_number)
```

which gives

```
   school_number cats       pct
1          10502    1  66.66667
2          10502    2  33.33333
3          10502    3   0.00000
4          10502    4   0.00000
5          10503    1   0.00000
6          10503    2   0.00000
7          10503    3 100.00000
8          10503    4   0.00000
9          10505    1   0.00000
10         10505    2  33.33333
11         10505    3  66.66667
12         10505    4   0.00000
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @akrun, you probably have called `plyr` and `dplyr` packages previously. Since `summaris(z)e` valids in both packages, you could specify by adding the package prior to the function name i.e. `dplyr::fun(argument...)`.